# knockout: how to bind a class from a property, and add static classes

Tags: knockout.js

(using ko 2.2.1)

I have a collection:

```
[
    { name: "foo", type: "bar" },
    { name: "zap", type: "fox" }
]
```

I want that to be bound to a ul/li list so that end result looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="icon bar">foo</li>
  <li class="icon fox">zap</li>
</ul>
```

I can bind a single class, but combining a class from data, and adding a static class is not working.

To be clear, set of types is not defined, so anything given as "type:" in the data should be added as a class on the li element

Comment: What have you tried? I'm pretty sure if you just add the class `icon` as normal in html and then bind to `css`, it will add the class to any existing classes.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't show what is not working...

However you can use the `text` and the [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) (which just add and remove classes it doesn't do anything with the already existing ones) on the same element.

So the following binding generates your sample output if you pass your array in the `data` property:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
    <li class="icon" data-bind="text: name, css: type" />
</ul>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY6bN/).

Comment: Wow. Pretty slick.  I'm headed to the Knockout tutorial now.

Comment: @nemesv: I thought I've tried that, PEBKAC I guess. Thank you. Bonus points - can I bind multiple classes from data?

Comment: There is two way to add multiple classes the first is to use an object where the property names are used as the classes. The second version you can have a space separated list of classnames. see both version: http://jsfiddle.net/ZY6bN/1/

Comment: your example does not work with ko v2.1 (I was mistaken, I use 2.1, not 2.2). 2.1 turns a string into an array and adds "0 1 2 3..."

Comment: Yes this has been change between 2.1 and 2.2. Why don't you update to 2.2? In 2.1 you have to use the `attr` binding as a workaround to set the class but in this case you need to set your static class "icon" also with kncokout... http://jsfiddle.net/ZY6bN/2/